# auto scroll to the bottom of container in sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2, scrollbar, containers

I have a view that contains 2 parts:
 + Part 1: an ADD button
 + Part 2: a container LIST that has scroll attribute is auto.

When user clicks on button ADD, the system will add a container to container LIST. User can add as much as they want.

But my container LIST has limit height so I want to scroll to new container that added to container LIST when user clicks ADD button.
Anyone help me. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to use:

```
var scroller = pan.getScrollable().getScroller();
scroller.scrollToEnd(true);
```

But it's not working.
Then I tried another way:

```
var scroller = pan.getScrollable().getScroller();
scroller.scrollTo(x,y,true);// y = 100000000000
```

It's work :)

Comment: At last i found you! Thanks!

Comment: First I thought this is a really bad hack which I don't want to do. Then I tried the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455413/scroller-scrollto-in-sencha-touch-dont-work-if-not-launched-manually-just-befor, but this also didn't work. After some more research in the Internet I finally gave up and ended up using your hack. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: BTW, there could be another solution for this: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?262467-Scroll-to-bottom-of-list-when-updated&p=1039640&viewfull=1#post1039640
But I didn't try it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var scroller = myListObject.getScrollable().getScroller();
scroller.scrollToEnd();
```